# When joining the same table, how to put the joined data in separate rows rather than separate columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, window-functions, exists

Let us say, I have a query like the following.

```
select * from `Students` s1
join `Students` s2
on s2.id = s1.id + 1 and s2.marks >= 80 and s1.marks >= 80
```

In this case, the data for `s1` and `s2` would be put into two separate columns, but how can I put them into separate rows instead?.

Here is a sample data:

```
+---+------+
| id| marks| 
+---+------|
| 1 | 88   |
| 2 | 77   |
| 3 | 81   |
| 4 | 82   |
| 5 | 75   |
| 6 | 80   |
| 7 | 90   |
| 8 | 93   |
+---+------+
```

What I want is rows (ordered by `id`) with two consecutive 80+ marks to be shown. For example, in this case, rows with id 3, 4, 6, 7 and 8 would be shown.

Comment: please provide few sample data with table structure and expected output.

Comment: You've been a SO user for 10 years, you surely must know that you're expected to provide sample data and expected results for a SQL question.

Comment: @Stu Just added the Sample Data and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your version of MySql is 8.0+ you can use `LAG()` and `LEAD()` window functions to check for the previous and next values of `marks` of each row:

```
SELECT id, marks
FROM (
  SELECT *,
         LAG(marks) OVER (ORDER BY id) prev_marks,
         LEAD(marks) OVER (ORDER BY id) next_marks
  FROM students       
) t
WHERE marks >= 80 AND (prev_marks >= 80 OR next_marks >= 80)
ORDER BY id;
```

For previous versions use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT s1.*
FROM students s1
WHERE s1.marks >= 80
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM students s2
  WHERE s2.id IN (s1.id - 1, s1.id + 1) AND s2.marks >= 80
)
ORDER BY s1.id;
```

Or, with a self join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s1.*
FROM students s1 INNER JOIN students s2
ON s2.id IN (s1.id - 1, s1.id + 1)
WHERE s1.marks >= 80 AND s2.marks >= 80
ORDER BY s1.id;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6cf34e49a9c1ef4fa07005dec726a781).

Answer (score 0):

As stated without seeing your data what I guess is that you can use union in your query

```
SELECT
  s1.*
FROM
  `students` s1
  JOIN students s2
    ON s2.id = s1.id + 1
    AND s2.marks >= 80
    AND s1.marks >= 80
UNION
SELECT
  s2.*
FROM
  `students` s1
  JOIN students s2
    ON s2.id = s1.id + 1
    AND s2.marks >= 80
    AND s1.marks >= 80
ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: That would work, sure, but isn't there a more elegant solution to this?

Comment: Another solution is posted with a different approach by a senior member definitely that should help you out.